# How to use this class in my code

Tags: c#, list, sorting

I saw this natural sorting class that Ian Griffiths created (http://www.interact-sw.co.uk/iangblog/2007/12/13/natural-sorting) in C#.

I wanted to use it to sort a List of objects in my own code by the name of the object (also, how would I do it by a field in an object), how would I do so?

I tried, that came up with errors...

```
    System.Func<MyObjectClass, string> ConvertMyObject = str =>
    {
        return str.ToString();
    };
    listObjects = listObjects.OrderBy(str => Regex.Split(str, "([0-9]+)").Select(ConvertMyObject), new EnumerableComparer<MyObjectClass>());
```

Thanks!

```
/// <summary>
/// Compares two sequences.
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T">Type of item in the sequences.</typeparam>
/// <remarks>
/// Compares elements from the two input sequences in turn. If we
/// run out of list before finding unequal elements, then the shorter
/// list is deemed to be the lesser list.
/// </remarks>
public class EnumerableComparer<T> : IComparer<IEnumerable<T>>
{
/// <summary>
/// Create a sequence comparer using the default comparer for T.
/// </summary>
public EnumerableComparer()
{
    comp = Comparer<T>.Default;
}

/// <summary>
/// Create a sequence comparer, using the specified item comparer
/// for T.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="comparer">Comparer for comparing each pair of
/// items from the sequences.</param>
public EnumerableComparer(IComparer<T> comparer)
{
    comp = comparer;
}

/// <summary>
/// Object used for comparing each element.
/// </summary>
private IComparer<T> comp;


/// <summary>
/// Compare two sequences of T.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="x">First sequence.</param>
/// <param name="y">Second sequence.</param>
public int Compare(IEnumerable<T> x, IEnumerable<T> y)
{
    using (IEnumerator<T> leftIt = x.GetEnumerator())
    using (IEnumerator<T> rightIt = y.GetEnumerator())
    {
        while (true)
        {
            bool left = leftIt.MoveNext();
            bool right = rightIt.MoveNext();

            if (!(left || right)) return 0;

            if (!left) return -1;
            if (!right) return 1;

            int itemResult = comp.Compare(leftIt.Current, rightIt.Current);
            if (itemResult != 0) return itemResult;
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. What have you tried so far that isn't working for you? What exactly is it you're asking? It appears your post is "I have this code. How do I use it?", in which case it's not an appropriate question here. We're not a tutorial site. If you have specific questions, please ask them and we'll see if we can help. Thanks. :-)

Comment: Why don't you ask this code author instead?

Comment: thanks, i didn't mean to ask for a "tutorial" per se. So what I tried is Enumerable<MyObjectClass> test = new Enumerable<MyObjectClass>(); listObjects.Sort(test.Compare());  // List<MyObjectClass> listObjects

Comment: I dont understand the problem, its easy to implement this code in your own project. There is even an example of how you call the method in the link you provided: http://www.interact-sw.co.uk/iangblog/2007/12/13/natural-sorting

Comment: I didn't quite understand what was happening in the example. Actually I initially thought it was in Python lol

Comment: I tried something like this, but get a number of errors...
  System.Func<MyObjectClass, string> ConvertMyObject = str =>
  {
   return str.ToString();
  };
  listObjects = listObjects.OrderBy(str => Regex.Split(str, "([0-9]+)").Select(ConvertMyObject), new EnumerableComparer<MyObjectClass>());

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The natural sorting method he provides is really useful when the 'normal' sort doesn't comply with with what you need. For instance, the 'normal' way to sort strings is alphabetical, so we need a workaround.

However, in your example you're trying to sort a custom object--which means that you get to  supply your own sort rules!

To define those rules, [implement IComparable](http://www.dotnetperls.com/icomparable) with your own comparison based on whatever field you choose from the object.

You could have the sort first check 'Name' field you described, and if they're a match, then compare the numerical field.

However, if you truly need natural sorting on a given field, then you can still adapt the blog's handy EnumerableComparer with this easier to understand technique. (simply comparing the left's  Regex.Split(str.Replace(" ", ""), "([0-9]+)").Select() to the right's)

Finally, if it's the LINQ expression that's giving you a hard time, [check out this LINQ-less approach.](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22517/Natural-Sort-Comparer)

Comment: thank you for the explanation (and patience), i'll have a look at what you suggest and work it out myself.